# macOS: Open GUI application over SSH not possible

Tags: permissions, mac-osx, ansible, graphical-user-interface

I'm working on automating the installation of a macOS application using Ansible. I am installing the application by copying its .app folder from a .dmg image to the /Applications/ directory.

After doing this, I attempt to launch the application via SSH with:

```
sudo -u buildworker open -a /Applications/Name.app
```

However, I receive the following error message:

> The application /Applications/Name.app cannot be opened for an
> unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5
> "Launch failed."

Strangely, if I log into the machine's GUI and manually start the application once, subsequent attempts to launch it via SSH work perfectly.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Is there any way to "pre-initialize" the application so that it can be launched via SSH without a manual first-time GUI launch?

OS: macOS Monterey (12.6.7)

- The app is not in com.apple.quarantine
- I disabled gatekeeper The app
- The app is completly signed for macOS

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to login directly as "buildworker" user through SSH using X11 forwarding ?

You will need to enable X11 forwarding on both the server ([https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/openssh-server/sshd_config.5.en.html#X11Forwarding~2](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/openssh-server/sshd_config.5.en.html#X11Forwarding%7E2)) and the client ("-X" cli option).